# my javascript bar chart doesn't come up on my index.html page

Tags: javascript, html

Heyy, I've been working on my web app project and I needed to do a graph so I tried it separately in another file and it works so well but when I paste in the index.html it doesn't I don't know why

the one pie chart is working perfectly but not the bar chart. I've been trying to change the version, etc but nothing works at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<title>˚₊‧ Welcome Page ‧₊˚</title>
<link href="indexstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome, <b> ♡</b></h1>
<div class="topsection">
<div class="leftside">
<h2>Active Population</h2>
<ul id="activepopulation"><li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2020)">AIs - F2020 (2)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2021)">AIs - S2021 (2)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2020)">CS - F2020 (4)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2021)">CS - S2021 (3)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2020)">DSA - F2020 (7)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2021)">DSA - S2021 (4)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2020)">ISM - F2020 (4)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2021)">ISM - S2021 (3)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2020)">SE - F2020 (4)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2021)">SE - S2021 (4)</li></ul>
</div>
<div id="rightside">
<div id="piechart">
<canvas height="400" id="pieChart" width="400"></canvas>
<script>
var data = [
  {
      value: 4,
      color:"#fcedf5",
      highlight: "#e9cdfa",
      label: "AIs"
  },
  {
      value: 7,
      color: "#fad7e9",
      highlight: "#e9cdfa",
      label: "CS"
  },
  {
      value: 11,
      color: "#fcbdde",
      highlight: "#e9cdfa",
      label: "DSA"
  },
  {
      value: 7,
      color: "#ffb0d9",
      highlight: "#e9cdfa",
      label: "ISM"
  },
  {
      value: 8,
      color: "#fc9acd",
      highlight: "#e9cdfa",
      label: "SE"
  }];
var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottomsection">
<div class="leftside">
<h2>Overall atendance</h2>
<ul id="attendance"><li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2020)">AIs - F2020 (69%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2021)">AIs - S2021 (78%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2020)">CS - F2020 (70%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2021)">CS - S2021 (67%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2020)">DSA - F2020 (68%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2021)">DSA - S2021 (76%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2020)">ISM - F2020 (71%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2021)">ISM - S2021 (66%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2020)">SE - F2020 (74%)</li>
<li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2021)">SE - S2021 (68%)</li></ul>
</div>
<div id="rightside">
<div id="barChart">
<canvas height="400" id="barChart" width="400"></canvas>
<script>
var data = {
    labels: ["AIs", "CS", "DSA", "ISM", "SE"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "2020 Intake",
            data: [0.69, 0.7, 0.68, 0.71, 0.74],
            backgroundColor: ["#fcedf5", "#fad7e9", "#fcbdde", "#ffb0d9", "#fc9acd"],
            borderColor: "#fff",
             borderWidth: 1
        },{
            label: "2021 Intake",
            data: [0.78, 0.67, 0.76, 0.71, 0.74],
            backgroundColor: ["#fcedf5", "#fad7e9", "#fcbdde", "#ffb0d9", "#fc9acd"],
            borderColor: "#fff",
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };

var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
            x: {
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                ticks: {
                callback: function(value) {
                return (value * 100) + "%";
                }}}}}
        });</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="footer">Website last generation 10th Feb 2024 ₍ᐢ.  ̫.ᐢ₎ </p>
<script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function populationfunction(population,year){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8001/students",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                key1: population,
                key2: year
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert('Error: ' + xhr.status) 
            }
        })
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there something overriding it? Or there is another element with the same id?

Comment: Not really, I check id multiple time and it's already correct

Comment: Share the index.html file as well

Comment: okay I just edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's how I got it working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" />
  <title>˚₊‧ Welcome Page ‧₊˚</title>
  <link href="indexstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>

  <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>-->


</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome, <b> ♡</b></h1>
  <div class="topsection">
    <div class="leftside">
      <h2>Active Population</h2>
      <ul id="activepopulation">
        <li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2020)">AIs - F2020 (2)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2021)">AIs - S2021 (2)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2020)">CS - F2020 (4)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2021)">CS - S2021 (3)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2020)">DSA - F2020 (7)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2021)">DSA - S2021 (4)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2020)">ISM - F2020 (4)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2021)">ISM - S2021 (3)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2020)">SE - F2020 (4)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2021)">SE - S2021 (4)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightside">
      <div id="piechart">
        <canvas height="400" id="pieChartCanvas" width="400"></canvas>
        <script>
          var data = [{
              value: 4,
              color: "#fcedf5",
              highlight: "#e9cdfa",
              label: "AIs"
            },
            {
              value: 7,
              color: "#fad7e9",
              highlight: "#e9cdfa",
              label: "CS"
            },
            {
              value: 11,
              color: "#fcbdde",
              highlight: "#e9cdfa",
              label: "DSA"
            },
            {
              value: 7,
              color: "#ffb0d9",
              highlight: "#e9cdfa",
              label: "ISM"
            },
            {
              value: 8,
              color: "#fc9acd",
              highlight: "#e9cdfa",
              label: "SE"
            }
          ];
          var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChartCanvas").getContext("2d");
          var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(data);
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomsection">
    <div class="leftside">
      <h2>Overall atendance</h2>
      <ul id="attendance">
        <li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2020)">AIs - F2020 (69%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('AIs',2021)">AIs - S2021 (78%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2020)">CS - F2020 (70%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('CS',2021)">CS - S2021 (67%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2020)">DSA - F2020 (68%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('DSA',2021)">DSA - S2021 (76%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2020)">ISM - F2020 (71%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('ISM',2021)">ISM - S2021 (66%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2020)">SE - F2020 (74%)</li>
        <li onclick="populationfunction('SE',2021)">SE - S2021 (68%)</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="rightside">
      <div id="barChart" style="height: auto; width: 500px;">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
        <canvas id="barChartCanvas"></canvas>
        <script>
          var data = {
            labels: ["AIs", "CS", "DSA", "ISM", "SE"],
            datasets: [{
              label: "2020 Intake",
              data: [0.69, 0.7, 0.68, 0.71, 0.74],
              backgroundColor: ["#fcedf5", "#fad7e9", "#fcbdde", "#ffb0d9", "#fc9acd"],
              borderColor: "#fff",
              borderWidth: 1
            }, {
              label: "2021 Intake",
              data: [0.78, 0.67, 0.76, 0.71, 0.74],
              backgroundColor: ["#fcedf5", "#fad7e9", "#fcbdde", "#ffb0d9", "#fc9acd"],
              borderColor: "#fff",
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          };

          var ctx = document.getElementById("barChartCanvas").getContext("2d");
          var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: data,
            options: {
              indexAxis: 'y',
              scales: {
                x: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 1,
                  ticks: {
                    callback: function(value) {
                      return (value * 100) + "%";
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="footer">Website last generation 10th Feb 2024 ₍ᐢ. ̫.ᐢ₎ </p>
  <script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function populationfunction(population, year) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8001/students",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          key1: population,
          key2: year
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert('Error: ' + xhr.status)
        }
      })
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Changes:

1. changed the id of barChart to barChartCanvas, as getContext() gave an error as it tried to get the context of the div element. (Though it worked for the first graph I also changed it there)
2. Added the link to the javascript file you provided in the code before you showed the index file directly above the barChartCanvas. I tried putting it into the head, but then the first graph didn't show up. I suspect that one is overwrighting the other in some way, but don't know how.
3. added `style="width:500px height:auto"` to barChart, as adding witdh and height to the barChartCanvas didn't work (maybe due to the other library)

It's not perfect but it works, and maybe with that you know how to improve it.

Comment: OMGGGGG it's workkkkkk, Thank you so muchhhh ;--;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you put the first `<script>` into `head`, the `<canvas>` into the `<body>`, and the second `<script>` below `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your version of the **Chart.js CDN**.

Use this instead and it should work:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is not the issue. because if it was the issue it would work on the other pages.